# How to copy iis property settings from one server to another

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

I just needed to copy the Default Website Property settings everytime a new test server is to be set up. It is tedious to compare and do that manually everytime and there is a chance of mistakes.

I know we can use the **Web Deployment Tool** to sync websites between a local and remote IIS server. But all I need is copying the iis settings and not the websites in it.

If I use the **Web Deployment Tool** it copies even my website files which are on the Default Web Site (No Virtual Directory).

Comment: Is this really IIS 5?  If so, then there are some limited export/import options.  You tagged IIS5, but Web Deployment Tool is for IIS 6 and 7.  If you are indeed using IIS6 or higher, Web Deploy can be tweaked to copy exactly what you want, and nothing further.  Let us know, and I can provide details if t
hats the case.

Comment: Yes this is iis 5. I tried creating a package with the msdeploy.exe and it works fine. Seems it is backward compatible with iis 5. But the problem is it is copying all the aspx and other files as well. Let me know if we can tweak this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've tagged your question with IIS5. I've used the metabase import export tool before with some success, although it is targetted for IIS6 so I don't know if it would work for you. Perhaps worth looking at though:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/637e4ec0-d9ef-4115-935b-47087870e01a.mspx?mfr=true